# Command prompt goes blank

Tags: python

Whenever i go to run the program it prompts me to enter the name when i do so it just sends the line where you type to the next line and i cant do anything but when i close it i see whatever i ctrl c the program i see whatever i should have been typing #This program searches for employees by name/prints info

```
#set a boolean value to False
found = False
#get the search value name
search = input("Enter a name to search for: ")
#open the employe file in read mode
empFile = open('employees.txt','r')
#read the first line/the name field in the 1st rec
name = empFile.readline()
#if field has records, continue processing
while name != '':
    #get id and dept
    id = empFile.readline()
    dept = empFile.readline()
    #strip newline from each string
    name = name.rstrip('\n')
    id = id.rstrip('\n')
    dept = dept.rstrip('\n')
    #determine if name matches search
    if name == search:
        #display record
        print('Name: ', name)
        print('ID: ', id)
        print('Department: ', dept)
        print()
        found = True
        #Read the name in the next record
        name = empFile.readline()
#close the file
empFile.close()
#If search item not found, print message
if found == False:
    print("The name was not found in  the file")
```

## Traceback

> Enter a name to search for: as Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\adam\Desktop\CIS201\searchRecords.py", line 13, in
>   
>       id = empFile.readline()   File "C:\Users\adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py",
>   line 22, in decode
>       def decode(self, input, final=False): KeyboardInterrupt

as requested the expected result should be it finding the name (or not depending on what you put) and either printing the name id and department or if you put a name that doesnt exist it should display the error message "The name was not found"

Comment: not clear what u asking, please provide actual and expected result

Comment: done thank you check the edit

Comment: nvm someone fixed it but thank you ill try to be more specific next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code only works for the first name in the file because you are not re-reading.  The problem is these lines should not be indented inside the `if`:

```
    #Read the name in the next record
    name = empFile.readline()
```

So, indented inside the loop:

```
if name == search:
    #display record
    print('Name: ', name)
    print('ID: ', id)
    print('Department: ', dept)
    print()
    found = True
#Read the name in the next record
name = empFile.readline()
```

There are many improvements that could be made, but fix one thing at a time.

Comment: This worked thank you ill accept the answer when the time restriction passes.